# how to get enum by index and vice versa

Tags: flutter, enums

I just looked for the below questions and did not find a complete answer. So this is what I found out

1. how can I get an enum value by index
2. how can I get the index position of an enum value

Answer (score 4):

for the following enum

```dart
enum Status { 
   none, 
   running, 
   stopped, 
   paused 
}
```

1. `Status.values[1]` provides `Status.running`
2. `Status.running.index` provides `1`

if you have a variable `Status myStatus;` you can substitute `Status.running` with `myStatus`